# Can multiple Threads enter into InsertDAO?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have a Client class which invokes MyService class's execute method. This method will in turn calls a InsertDAO class. This InsertDAO has state with instance variables. This is invoked from execute method of MyService class only. One cannot directly invoke InsertDAO class.

I am not creating any threads but my App Server may create threads on Client class. Now, I want to understand how this will affect InsertDAO class.

1. Can multiple threads access an object of InsertDAO simultaneously? -- Yes/No
2. When threads are spawned on Client class, the same instance of MyService class is given to all threads on Client. Then every thread should call "execute" method of MyService. This means every thread has its own instance of InsertDAO (I am creating InsertDAO object inside execute method of MyService class). If so, multiple threads cannot enter into InsertDAO simultaneously. Is my understanding correct?
3. How is it possible for multiple threads to enter into MyService.execute() -- Some explanation, if this is true.
4. How is it possible for multiple threads to enter into InsertDAO class? -- Some explanation, if this is true.
5. How can I make it threadsafe without impacting performance?

Experts, please share your thoughts on this. Below is my code.

```
//code starts here
public class Client{
    public void performExecution(){
        InvoiceVO createInvoiceVO = new InvoiceVO();
        MyService service = new MyService();
            createInvoiceVO = service.execute(createInvoiceVO);
        //retrieve successful/failure information from createInvoiceVO
    }
}

public class MyService{
    public InvoiceVO execute(InvoiceVO createInvoiceVO){
        InsertDAO insertDAO = new InsertDAO();
            insertDAO.process(createInvoiceVO);
    }
}

public class InsertDAO{
    private List<LineItem> lineItemsList = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
    private List<TaxVO> taxVOList = new ArrayList<TaxVO>();
    private Connection connection = null;

    public InvoiceVO process(InvoiceVO createInvoiceVO){
        this.lineItemsList = createInvoiceVO.getLineItemsList();
        this.taxVOList = createInvoiceVO.getTaxVOList();

        connection = getConnection();
        //insert tax vo objects
        insertTaxVOObjects(taxVOList);

        //insert line items
        insertLineItems(this.lineItemsList);

        //commit operation

        //close connection
        closeConnection();
    }

    private void insertTaxVOObjects(List<TaxVO> taxVOList){
        //code to insert TaxVO objects  
    }

    private void insertLineItems(List<LineItem> lineItemsList){
        //code to insert LineItem objects
    }

    private void getConnection(){
        //code to return connection
    }

    private void closeConnection(){
        //code to close connection
    }
}
```

Comment: edited to refer object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not quite asking the right question, threads don't enter classes, they enter objects; we need to look at the life cycle of the objects and when threads are created.

Now I don't understand your execution environment - I'm not clear where threads are created, but I'll assume that somehow Client Objects are created and the performExecution() method of each object may run on its own thread. The question now is whether any one of your InsertDAO objects might be accessed from two threads at the same time or whether two InsertDAO objects might share some data and hence two threads might interfere.

Now first we notice that each InsertDAO object is separate, they have variables but those variables are not static. You have for example

```
this.lineItemsList
```

So that data is owned by a single object instance, no other object (possibly in another thread) could see the data attached to **this**. Note if you had **static** data all instance could see it and you would have a problem. First rule: NO STATIC DATA, unless you protect it with synchronised access.

The one place where you have a potential problem is that you ask for a connection. Now connections are usually pooled, we really don't want to open a connection for every request, instead we get one from a pool and return when we've used it. The whole idea is that threads share the same pool. So the general principle here is that anything that your InsertDAO objects use that they do not have as a member variable must be **thread-safe**, that is the author must have written it in the expectation of multiple threads accessing it. A shared pool: author must have used synchronized access of some sort. Rule 2: Look at what you use as well as your own code.

Last bit, could two threads share a single InsertDAO object? To answer that look at how you create them:

```
public InvoiceVO execute(InvoiceVO createInvoiceVO){
    InsertDAO insertDAO = new InsertDAO();
        insertDAO.process(createInvoiceVO);
}
```

Here you create the object, call it's method and return (implicitly releasing the object), no other thread can see this, it's local on your stack. Hence we know that only one thread uses one InsertDAO object. Rule three: it's the caller that determines how many threads can see an object. In your case you've ensured one thread.

Comment: Great. You have blown off my doubts on whether multiple threads can access InsertDAO object at a time. Reference to connection pool where multi threading is possible from outside, is a nice point which did not strike to me. So, if we create a "gate" ( MyService.execute() ) and if that has only member variables and every (like InsertDAO) non-static stateful objects are protected from multiple threads. That is great to know. Cheers. Thanks for your explanation